# Android GoogleMap: add a marker in a form of a line with angle from origin

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, angle

I have a list of coordinates (yLat, xLon) with an angle (bearing in degrees, e.g. 160) to draw on my map, and I would like to do it with lines or arrows which start from the coordinates and head to the bearing.

I started to do it using a Polyline:

```
LatLng thisPoint = new LatLng(yLat, xLon);
Polyline site = googleMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                    .add(thisPoint, new LatLng(11.593, 104.932))
                    .width(5)
                    .color(Color.MAGENTA));
```

However the line is too small when I zoom out: I want the line to **be always the same size on the screen** to show the direction to the user and independently of the zoom level.

See the example below: on the first screenshot the magenta line is big enough, but on the second one after zooming out, the line becomes smaller and we cannot see the direction as clearly.

[image: in this screenshot the line is big enough to be visible]

[image: after zooming out, the same line is too small to be clearly visible]

Any suggestion?

Comment: can you paste your screen shot  before zoom in and after zoom out

Comment: I added 2 screenshots to show the difference, thank you!

Comment: how it possible when you zoom out your line will also reduced as your location area also reduced. these is the default behavior of google map.

Comment: yes, that is why I don't want to use a map, but an icon/marker which I can rotate according to a specific angle, any idea?

Comment: you cannot set these even if you find any solution you need to stop rotating of map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the best way to address my need: I created a marker with an icon with a vertical arrow in the middle of a transparent square (R.mipmap.ic_arrow_up), then I create the marker applying a rotation of the desired angle:

```
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(myLatLng)
        .title(myTitle)
        .snippet(mySnippet)
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.ic_arrow_up))
        .rotation(myAngle));
```

Hope this helps other people